# Select Mongoose Model Based on Express Route

Tags: express, routes, mongoose

I think this might be a basic question, but looking for the best approach.

I'm building an express app that should route to one of four different Mongoose models depending on the route.

Something like this:

```
app.get('/:trial', function(req, res){
    var trial = req.params.trial;
    trial.find(function(err, records) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(records); // returns all trial records in JSON format
    });
});
```

I have 4 mongoose models named: trial1, trial2, trial3, trial4. I would like the trial parameter of the URL to determine which collection gets queried. Obviously the above won't work, but what should I do instead of rewriting the route four times instead?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get models by name:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.get('/:trial', function(req, res){
    var trial = req.params.trial;
    mongoose.Model(trial).find(function(err, records) {
        if (err) {
            // Return when we end the response here...
            return res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(records); // returns all trial records in JSON format
    });
});
```

Depending on circumstances, I would validate the value of `trial` first (so requesting `/User` doesn't dump all users to the client, for instance).

Comment: Awesome. mongoose.Model(trial) was exactly what I needed. Thanks!